# Adding content to outer template from inner template with Smarty

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I have a site with a fairly complex structure of Smarty templates.  For this question, suppose I have an outer template which includes (with `{include}`) one or more inner templates that are optionally included, depending on the data being displayed:

```
Outer Template (with <html>, <head>, and <body> tags)
    - Inner Template A (various content)
    - Inner Template B (more content)
```

Sometimes, one of these inner templates needs to reference additional CSS files.  I would prefer to have these within my `<head>` tag, for efficiency and to avoid FOUC.  Is it possible to set some variable from `Inner Template A` that adds the appropriate `<link>` tag to `<head>` within `Outer Template`?

I was able to find someone who created [a module to do something similar](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/index.php?/topic/34227-module-add-css-to-head-tag/page__view__findpost__p__264188), but I don't know how I would set the necessary variables from the template to make it work in my case.  I am using Smarty 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue some time ago. My solution is maybe dirty but maybe it could help you.

```
$css = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/file.css">';
$smarty->registerFilter('output',create_function('$output','return preg_replace(\'/(<\/head>)/i\',\''.$css.'$1\',$output,1);'));
```

If you wrap this in a function, you can simply add css to your head section from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1:**

Wrap the same logic around the style sheet in your head that you use for displaying template A or B.

**Idea 2:**

*Template 1 (Top Level):*

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whatevs1">
{block name="childStyles"}
{/block}
```

*Template 2 (Child Template):*

```
{block name="childStyles"}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whatevs2">
{/block}
```

**A side note:**

I understand the want to be W3 compliant using includes for stylesheets in HEAD but including them within the body wont break your html, even in IE7...

Comment: Idea 1 is what I'm moving to at the moment.  We do have stylesheets in the body, and that does work.  However, it is prone to FOUC issues when JavaScript is in the `<head>`.  I will look into `{block}`.  Thanks!

Comment: @Brad Javascript confilcts can be resolved using onload declorations.

Comment: I am aware.  It's a pretty complicated mess.  Until I get the time to fix it right, this is what I am attempting to do.  I've got 13,000 templates to wrangle, and a bunch of JavaScript to refactor.  Also, I was looking at `{block}`, and it seems that only works for inherited templates.  My templates are simply using `{include}`.

Comment: @Brad Then inherit the pieces you need so you can reference block.

Comment: Yes, I will probably have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar obstacle a few years ago. Since smarty templates are almost all the time filled with php code, my solution is just declaring a special variable/array for this purpose in php, then looping through the array in your head template / outer template.

Example:

```
$your_special_css = array('css1.css', 'css2.css');
```

Somewhere else in your code...

```
$your_special_css[] = 'css3.css';
```

...and then give it to the template:

```
$your_smarty_template->assign('your_css', $your_special_css);
```

Then your outer template would look like this:

```
<head>
 ...
{foreach $your_css as $css}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/{$css}">
{/foreach}
...
</head>
```

Same works for jscript-files, too.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately, I don't think this will work in my situation.  Only the inner template has the name of the CSS file it needs, and if I were to set a variable from that inner template, I believe the outer template would have been already processed.